# How to drop an index called 'index' from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, key, innodb, myisam

This question has been asked before, but I think this is a special case?

I'm trying to convert a table from myisam to innodb and most solutions I see recommend dropping the  fulltext key first (otherwise it doesn't work)

So I do `show create table blah;`

And I see the fulltext key

```
yadda yadda yadda
FULLTEXT KEY `index` (`index`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM yadda yadda yadda
```

But when I try to do

```
alter table blah drop index index;
```

I get

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index' at line 1

The syntax looks fine to me.  Now what?  This table was created by a WordPress plugin and unfortunately there's nothing in Google explaining how to convert this particular table to innodb.  I suppose I can leave it as myisam but I'm stubborn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same as creating time, use backticks to quote it.

```
alter table blah drop index `index`;
```

Comment: That was fast, thanks it worked!  The first thing I tried was single quotes but my font is small, I would not have thought to try  backticks without your help.